# Class Based View Filtering Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

i have a class based view that display me all the products for all the restaurants , but i want to display just the products of the actual restaurants using request.user.restaurant but that is don't work for me that is display me all the restaurants and all the products ....

```
class MealListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset            = Meal.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = MealSerializer
    permission_classes  = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        qs = Meal.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=query, description__icontains=query)
        return qs

    def get_restaurant(self):
        qs = Meal.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get('')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(restaurant = self.request.restaurant.user).order_by("-id")
        return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use APIView instead of ListCreatAPIView

```
class MealListAPIView(APIView):

    serializer_class = MealSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        qs = Meal.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get('')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(restaurant = self.request.restaurant.user).order_by("-id")
            return self.serializer_class(data=qs, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For above case we only need to override the `get_queryset` method. The code will look like below

```
class MealListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Meal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MealSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(restarent=self.request.user.restaurant)
        q = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if q:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=q, description__icontains=q)
        return queryset
```